# oauth for getting accesstoken in linkedin using xcode for ios

Tags: ios, xcode, oauth, linkedin-api, access-token

I'm getting an error from the server while requesting for accesstoken in linked in:

---

> oauth_problem=signature_invalid&oauth_problem_advice=com.linkedin.security.auth.pub.LoginDeniedInvalidAuthTokenException%20while%20obtaining%20request%20token%20for%20%3APOST%26https%253A%252F%252Fapi.linkedin.com%252Fuas%252Foauth%252FaccessToken%26oauth_consumer_key%253Dma6wmdg1a0lb%2526oauth_nonce%253DVltw%2526oauth_signature_method%253DHMAC-SHA1%2526oauth_timestamp%253D1389012417%2526oauth_token%253D75--f8855da6-48eb-4df3-b0ea-865b5176ee4a%2526oauth_verifier%253D90683%2526oauth_version%253D1.0%0AOAU%3Ama6wmdg1a0lb%7C75--f8855da6-48eb-4df3-b0ea-865b5176ee4a%7C%2A01%7C%2A01%3A1389012417%3Ac1EHNqTOB7N%2B5BLY7NF2fWG3s4U%3D

---

i've set the reqest in the same format as specified in the https://developer.linkedin.com/oauth-test-console

i set the requset as:

> NSMutableString *parameterString = [[NSMutableString
>   alloc]initWithFormat:@""];

```
[parameterString appendFormat:@"oauth_callback=%@", [oauthCallback urlencode]];
[parameterString appendFormat:@"&oauth_consumer_key=%@", [oauthConsumerKey urlencode]];
[parameterString appendFormat:@"&oauth_nonce=%@", [oauthNonce urlencode]];
[parameterString appendFormat:@"&oauth_signature_method=%@", [oauthSignatureMethod urlencode]];
[parameterString appendFormat:@"oauth_token=\"%@\"", oauth_token];
[parameterString appendFormat:@"&oauth_timestamp=%@", [oauth_timestamp urlencode]];
[parameterString appendFormat:@"&oauth_version=%@", [oauthVersion urlencode]];

NSString *signatureBaseString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&%@&%@", httpMethod, [baseURL urlencode], [parameterString urlencode]];

NSString *signingKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&", [oauthConsumerSecret urlencode]];

NSString *oauthSignature = [self hmacsha1:signatureBaseString secret:signingKey];

NSMutableString *urlString = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithFormat:@""];

[urlString appendFormat:@"%@", baseURL];

NSMutableString *authHeader = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithFormat:@""];

[authHeader appendFormat:@"OAuth "];

[authHeader appendFormat:@"oauth_nonce=\"%@\",", [oauthNonce urlencode]];
[authHeader appendFormat:@"oauth_signature_method=\"%@\",", [oauthSignatureMethod urlencode]];
[authHeader appendFormat:@"oauth_timestamp=\"%@\",", [oauth_timestamp urlencode]];
[authHeader appendFormat:@"oauth_consumer_key=\"%@\",", [oauthConsumerKey urlencode]];
[authHeader appendFormat:@"oauth_token=\"%@\",", [oauth_token urlencode]];
[authHeader appendFormat:@"oauth_verifier=\"%@\",", [oauth_verifier urlencode]];
[authHeader appendFormat:@"oauth_signature=\"%@\",", [oauthSignature urlencode]];
[authHeader appendFormat:@"oauth_version=\"%@\"", [oauthVersion urlencode]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]] ;
[request setHTTPMethod:httpMethod];
[request setValue:authHeader forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

please help...
Thanks in advanced.. :)